# LinkedIn Logo not found in section invitations

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, images

The LinkedIn Logo is not found in the [invitations](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/invitations/) section on careers resulting in a 404 (NotFound)

```
GET https://developer.linkedin.com/sites/default/files/LinkedIn_Logo30px.png?v=bfb7dbbec6f4 404 (Not Found)
```

It seems that the image is moved to another location

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was an error [image: in] the code: the URL to the image was [image: in]correct.

This has been fixed, mean[image: in]g the image is now displayed correctly.

We now store the image on our own doma[image: in]n, so this shouldn't happen anymore.

Thank you for post[image: in]g a bug report!